# Teleporting a dynamic body on contact with kinematic body, to the opposite side of another kinematic body

Tags: box2d

I'm using `Box2d` as an engine in my game. There is a piece where non-physical behaviour will occur i.e teleporting.

I've developed a very simple teleporting method, however it does not account for the fact that the ball can collide with either of the two teleporters at any point. And also that the two teleporters travel up and down on the `y` axis.

Does anyone know of a formula I could use?

```
if (ball.getBody().getPosition().x > 0){

    ball.getBody().setTransform(
        new Vec2(
            getTarget().getBodyPosition().x - 1.5f,
            getTarget().getBodyPosition().y), 
        0.0f);
    ball.getBody().setLinearVelocity(ball.getLinearVelocity());

}else if (ball.getBody().getPosition().x < 0){

    ball.getBody().setTransform(
        new Vec2(
            getTarget().getBodyPosition().x + 1.5f,
            getTarget().getBodyPosition().y), 
        0.0f);
    ball.getBody().setLinearVelocity(ball.getLinearVelocity());
}
```

Ideally, I'd like if the ball collides with 1 of the teleporters it is transformed to the other teleporter at the opposite side. So the ball will continue on the exact same path.

The teleportation occurs as soon as the ball collides with the edge of one of the teleporters.

The ball is a `dynamic` body and both teleporters are `kinematic`.

Intended behaviour ..

[image: Intended behaviour]

Comment: Maybe try this: At the moment of collision you could calculate the vector between your ball center position and the first teleporter position. Then ball gets transformed to the other teleporters position with the previously calculated vector added.

Comment: wouldn't that still cause an infinite loop of teleporting? if I calculated a vector at the "moment of collision" and then transformed the ball this would teleport the ball into a position causing a collision with second teleporter.